# C# GUI Access Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, oracle, web

I have a web service running on a local server. In it I have a method that returns a json representation of an Oracle database query, which is converted from a `List<Dictionary<String, String>>` object.

I have a GUI program that needs the same data. If I try to move the query to the GUI, I have to require the user to install Oracle on there system, according to what I read after getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=...'

I don't want to make my users install Oracle on their system.

My solution has been to just access the existing logic running on a web service (.NET 3.5 WebForms App). I wrote another web service that returns the `List<Dictionary<String, String>>` object, instead of going through the hassle of converting it to a json object.

How can I get this from the GUI?

In my initial searches I found a few links that said it was possible, or some where they returned an object in json format. But nothing for what I was looking for explicitly.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

not quite following you but how about a web api?  here is one I was playing around with using the hr schema.  so create a web api project.  then open the tools library package manager and add the oracle driver. type in `Install-Package odp.net.managed`  then configure your connection string in your web config here is mine just a database on my local machine so I'll leave the password in.

`<add name="hr" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mydatabase))); User Id=hr; Password=fdsafdsafafads;" providerName="oracle.manaagedatacess.client" />`

then create your model/s here is one  employees

```
public class employee{
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone_number { get; set; }
            public DateTime hire_date { get; set; }
            public string job_id { get; set; }
            public decimal? salary { get; set; }
            public decimal? commission_pct { get; set; }
            public int? manager_id { get; set; }
            public int? department_id { get; set; } 
}
```

I then made a repository (if you use entity framework as opposed to ado you don't need these steps but I don't typically use entity framework)

```
namespace webApiOracle.Models
{
    internal class employeeRepository
    {
        internal static IEnumerable<employee> getAllEmployees()
        {
            List<employee> employees = new List<employee>();
            string sql = "SELECT * from employees";
            OracleDataReader rdr = dataHelper.getrdr(sql);
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    employee emp = getEmployee(rdr);
                    employees.Add(emp);
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            return employees;
        }

        internal static employee getEmployee(int id)
        {
            employee emp = null;
            string sql = "SELECT * from employees where employee_id = " + id;
            OracleDataReader rdr = dataHelper.getrdr(sql);
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    emp = getEmployee(rdr);

                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            return emp;
        }

        internal static employee add(employee emp)
        {
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter();
            string sql = "Insert into employees ";
            sql = sql + "(EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) ";
            sql = sql + "values (EMPLOYEES_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:first_name,:last_name,:email,:phone_number,sysdate,:job_id,:salary,:commission_pct,:manager_id,:department_id)";
            OracleConnection cn =
              new OracleConnection(
                  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                  ["hr"].ConnectionString);

            cn.Open();
            oda.InsertCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, cn);
            oda.InsertCommand.BindByName = true;
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":first_name", emp.first_name);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":last_name", emp.last_name);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":email", emp.email);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":phone_number", emp.phone_number);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":job_id", emp.job_id);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":salary", emp.salary);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":commission_pct", emp.commission_pct);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":manager_id", emp.manager_id);
            oda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":department_id", emp.department_id);
            int count = oda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql = "SELECT * from employees where employee_id = EMPLOYEES_SEQ.CURRVAL";
            OracleDataReader rdr = dataHelper.getrdr(sql);
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    emp = getEmployee(rdr);

                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            return emp;
        }

        internal static IEnumerable<employee> getEmployeesByVal(string key, string value)
        {
            List<employee> employees = new List<employee>();
            string sql = "SELECT * from employees where " + key + " = '" + value + "'";
            OracleDataReader rdr = dataHelper.getrdr(sql);
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    employee emp = getEmployee(rdr);
                    employees.Add(emp);
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            return employees;
        }

        private static employee getEmployee(OracleDataReader rdr)
        {
            employee emp = new employee
            {
                employee_id = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("EMPLOYEE_ID")),
                first_name = rdr["FIRST_NAME"].ToString(),
                last_name = rdr["LAST_NAME"].ToString(),
                email = rdr["EMAIL"].ToString(),
                phone_number = rdr["PHONE_NUMBER"].ToString(),
                hire_date = rdr.GetDateTime(rdr.GetOrdinal("HIRE_DATE")),
                job_id = rdr["JOB_ID"].ToString(),
                salary = dataHelper.decimalnullable(rdr, "SALARY"),
                commission_pct = dataHelper.decimalnullable(rdr, "COMMISSION_PCT"),
                manager_id = dataHelper.intnullable(rdr, "MANAGER_ID"),
                department_id = dataHelper.intnullable(rdr, "DEPARTMENT_ID")
            };
            return emp;
        }
    }
}
```

then make a web api controller go to the controller folder right click and pick empty web api controller.

```
public class employeeController : ApiController
    {



        public IEnumerable<employee> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            return employeeRepository.getAllEmployees();
        }

        //[Route("api/employee/{id:int}")]
        public employee getEmployee(int id) {
            return employeeRepository.getEmployee(id);
        }

        [Route("api/employee/{key}/{value}")]
        public IEnumerable<employee> getEmployeesByVal(string key, string value) {
            return employeeRepository.getEmployeesByVal(key, value);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public employee add(employee emp)
        {
            return employeeRepository.add(emp);
        }
    }
}
```

then when you want your json data just call the url so if I want all employees my url is /api/employee  if you want just one employee it with id of 100 would be /api/employee/100  if you want employees with last name king it would be /api/employee/last_name/king

there are tons of web api examples out there and a couple free ebooks if you want to check it out.

Comment: by the way if you are doing this for real use bind parameters not  sql concatenation like I did. I was just messing around on my local machine.